# How to get 1 Gbps on laptop?

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, internet-speed

So I have AU114TX, which has a 10/100 Base T. In my college, I get only 100 Mbps at max, where my fellow friends get 700 Mbps. But I do have a USB 3.0 port. So will buying a USB 3.0 to Ethernet adapter and CAT-7 Ethernet cable help me out?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "CAT-7 Ethernet cable" though... just a patch cord is not important, 1Gbps Ethernet only requires compatible equipment and cabling at CAT-5e standards. USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet adapter and a quality connection are all that is really needed, but this is all still infrastructure and PC dependent.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** USB3 has a maximum throughput of 4.7Gb/s, which is far more bandwidth than an Ethernet port needs for Gigabit connectivity. A Cat7 cable is more than sufficient, especially over long distances.

**Your mileage WILL vary!** Based on the cable/port quality, you may not be able  to attain 700Mb/s.

### Sources

[USB 3.0](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2360306/usb-3-0-speed-real-and-imagined.html)

[Cat7](https://www.loxone.com/enen/cat7-cable/)